# New Tab Hyperlink to PDF

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, hyperlink, compatibility

I noticed that if I create a hyperlink to a PDF with `target="_blank"` it doesn't open correctly. It opens up a new tab but doesn't load the PDF, it just shows a white screen. I'm using Google Chrome v.43. Has anyone else noticed this problem or found a fix?

I've tested this with Safari and with Firefox and both don't have any problems opening PDFs to a new tab. I've also tried disabling my add-ons in Chrome and using Incognito mode with no luck.

Test link: http://jsfiddle.net/fkfxoho0/

```
<a href="http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf" target="_blank">Optimization Starter Guide</a>
```

Video of Chrome v.42 and then the problem with v.43:
https://youtu.be/v_EAedODKfA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by iframes with [the `sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) (like JSFiddle), as this issue does not happen with links outside such iframes. The issue can be reproduced outside of JSFiddle with the following HTML files.

**frame.html**:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts" src="content.html"></iframe>
```

**content.html**:

```
<a href="https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_cg_ue.pdf">default</a>
<a href="https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_cg_ue.pdf" target="_blank">_blank</a>
<a href="https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_cg_ue.pdf" target="_top">_top</a>
```

With these sandbox values, the default target, `_blank`, and `_top` all fail to render a PDF, with the default failing to render in the iframe, and `_blank` and `_top` opening a new tab which fails (`_top` opens a new tab because of sandboxing).

If we add the `allow-top-navigation` sandbox value, we can make `_top` work as expected.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts" src="content.html"></iframe>
```

However, the new tab opened by `_blank` still fails to render the PDF. Even if I add all of the sandbox relaxing properties on MDN, the issue is still present (not that I expected adding `allow-pointer-lock` to do anything).

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock" src="content.html"></iframe>
```

The only way I can get `_blank` to work inside an iframe in Chrome 43 is to remove the `sandbox` attribute entirely.

```
<iframe src="content.html"></iframe>
```

Now the default target, `_blank`, and `_top` work as expected.

Unfortunately, removing the `sandbox` attribute isn't much of a workaround. If you are using it in the first place, you probably have a need for it. <s>I can't say for sure there isn't a security reason for blocking PDF files in a sandboxed iframe, but the user experience from this leads me to believe this is more-likely a bug.</s>

I've opened an a bug report for this issue, linking back to this question:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=505860

**UPDATE:** Turns out this is a by-design security feature, so it probably won't be returning to the Chrome 42 behavior, but a new sandbox option may be added in the future to relax this security feature.

**UPDATE-2:** The sandbox attribute that does allow this feature is 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox'. More info [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/)

Comment: I had to spend countless hours in researching this. And I can attest that the only way to fix the issue is to use `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` flag as part of CSP header or remove `sandbox` completely from the CSP header. Great stuff.